# "No cipher suites in common” error in Jetty

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, jetty

I've set up ssl connector in Jetty. It works fine at my dev machine running Windows 7, but fails at Linux dev server: Chrome/IE/C# client are not able to open a webpage and "No cipher suites in common” is displayed in Jetty debug log. 
I fetched javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine from SslConnectionFactory and printed list of supported chipher suites and it is the same for Windows/Linux machine (I'm running the same java 1.8.0.11). Could anyone suggest are any other chiphers except these one are used for SSL handshake?

```
2016-01-18 10:20:11,875 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] tty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory - SNI matching for type=host_name (0), value=x.com
2016-01-18 10:20:11,875 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] tty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory - SNI matched x.com->X509@18479e43(cert0,h=[x.com, y.com, z.com],w=[])
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] .ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager - Matched x.com with X509@18479e43(cert0,h=[x.com, y.com, z.com],w=[]) from [key]
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] .ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager - Chose alias null/RSA on 119c684e[SSLEngine[hostname=1.2.3.4 port=64350] SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] .ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager - Matched x.com with X509@18479e43(cert0,h=[x.com, y.com, z.com],w=[]) from [key]
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] .ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager - Chose alias null/RSA on 119c684e[SSLEngine[hostname=1.2.3.4 port=64350] SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] .ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager - Matched x.com with X509@18479e43(cert0,h=[x.com, y.com, z.com],w=[]) from [key]
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] .ssl.SniX509ExtendedKeyManager - Chose alias null/RSA on 119c684e[SSLEngine[hostname=1.2.3.4 port=64350] SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] ipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint - onClose SelectChannelEndPoint@5bdd29a4{/10.240.68.111:64350<->8443,CLOSED,in,out,-,-,3/30000,SslConnection}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] lipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - close SelectChannelEndPoint@5bdd29a4{/10.240.68.111:64350<->8443,CLOSED,in,out,-,-,3/30000,SslConnection}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] lipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$2@1fbd3777 on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@5e45d242 id=2 keys=1 selected=0
2016-01-18 10:20:11,877 DEBUG [qtp277169967-36] se.jetty.server.HttpConnection - 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1364)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:807)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:775)
```

Thanks!

UPD: Also there is an interesting behavior, if I import only one certificate it works fine, but there is an ssl warning in browser that certificate is signed by another one that is not provided. And if I import the whole certificate chain there is an error.

UPD 2: I ran SSL checker for problematic server and have

```
Supported versions: TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
Deflate compression: no
Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
  TLSv1.0
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  (TLSv1.1: idem)
  TLSv1.2
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
----------------------
Server certificate(s):
  XXX: CN=XXX, O=XXX, DC=XXX, DC=XXX
----------------------
Minimal encryption strength:     strong encryption (96-bit or more)
Achievable encryption strength:  strong encryption (96-bit or more)
```

The same list of chiphers is provided by server where I'm able to connect using browser, the only difference is in certificates.

UPD 3:
I checked certificate for another CN/SAN at this unix server and it works fine (just throw a invalid certificate host error). Looks like when CN/SAN record matches it runs additional validation that leads to this error?

Comment: Have you tried pointing the [Qualys SSL Server Tester](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) at your server?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, it is internal server so I can't reach it using such website unfortunately.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I added some test info from another tool

Comment: Perhaps there is an unsupported signature algorithm used somewhere along the chain. Or perhaps your chain is simply broken.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes, I had an idea about it, but the problem is that this keystore works on my windows machine (there is a warning that hostname doesn't match but I'm able to connect using browser).

Comment: It might be worth checking your `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security` file and check for references to `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/lib/security/nss.cfg`. If that file isn't present or misconfigured, you could have problems. If you're not using NSS, you might as well comment this line out.

Comment: Thanks, @Bruno, I checked this file in jre folder and there are no references to NSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was able to fix it: in keystore there were certificates inside keyfile and separately. I removed separate copies and it start to work. I don't know how it explain an issue that depends on hostname, just posting a solution if anyone has the same issue.
UPD: Also it helped to switch to .p12 keystore (where only certificate chain is inside and no key).

Comment: Was running into a similar issue where could not complete handshakes and this ended up being my solution too.

Answer (score 1):

In short, what your client is offering, and what the server has, are different.

This could be from something as simple as your certificates being DSA format, and your client not offering DSA (to fix this, make sure you use a more modern certificate format, at least RSA or better)

There are also a whole bunch of ciphers that are specifically excluded due to one vulnerability or another.

Using the `SSLEngine` to obtain the "supported" list isn't going to get you a real world answer.  All it tells you is what your Java is capable of, not what your specific connector configuration is setup to honor.

Use the `SslContextFactory`, but ask it what its included and excluded cipher suites are.  Or just turn on debugging for the `SslContextFactory` and look at the output it produces (which shows the included/excluded ciphers and protocols).

**Update:**

You didn't mention it was an SNI certificate, that narrows things down significantly.

For starters, you must use Jetty 9.3+, with Java 8+, no older version of Jetty or Java support SNI on the server side.

Lastly, make sure you have the `SecureRequestCustomizer` added to the `HttpConfiguration` in your SSL/TLS specific `Connector`, with the optional constructor to enable the `SNI` host check.

On the `jetty-distribution` you would do the following ...

```
$ mkdir snibase
$ cd snibase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=https,deploy
INFO: server          initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: ssl             initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: https           initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: deploy          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
DOWNLOAD: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/plain/jetty-server/src/test/config/etc/keystore?id=master to ${jetty.base}/etc/keystore
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/webapps
INFO: Base directory was modified
$ grep sni start.ini 
# jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck=true
$ edit start.ini
$ grep sni start.ini 
jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck=true
```

Comment: I checked certificate for another SNI for at htis unix server and it works fine (just throw a SNI error). Looks like when SNI record matches it runs additional validation that leads to this error? The list of supported chiphers is the same for unix/windows machines, so I think the reason is not in there setup but in checks for certificate validation.

Comment: Joakim, I double-checked and looks like I made a mistake in my edit and the issue is not for SNI error, we just have a CN/SAN records in certificate and when hosts matches these records client fails to connect to this server. I just saw a message about SNI matching in logs so it it was a misunderstanding from my side. But the problem is just for CN/SAN records. I tried to disable SNI using passing false to SecureRequestCustomizer but it doesn't help.